# Flask upgrade - Lots of "Exception ignored in..." messages in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

After upgrading to Flask 1.0 and potentially a few other libraries (running > pip3 install -r requirements.txt --upgrade) , I'm getting a lot of Exceptions in my console when running the local server environment which I didn't get before.

Any idea why?

Config: Mac OS X latest, PyCharm, Python 3.6.4, Flask 1.0

> Exception ignored in: .
>   at 0x117574e60> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py", line 428,
>   in 
>       if not rest or any(c not in s('0123456789') for c in rest): SystemError: error return without exception set
>
> Exception ignored in: . at 0x1176d00f8> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py", line 428,
>   in 
>       if not rest or any(c not in s('0123456789') for c in rest): SystemError: error return without exception set
>
> Exception ignored in: .
>   at 0x117574af0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py", line 428,
>   in 
>       if not rest or any(c not in s('0123456789') for c in rest): SystemError: error return without exception set
>
> Exception ignored in: . at 0x11489dc50> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Development &
>   Product/Project/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
>   line 1171, in 
>       if tokenName in fields), None) SystemError: error return without exception set Exception ignored in: . at 0x11489dc50> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Development &
>   Product/Project/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
>   line 1171, in 
>       if tokenName in fields), None) SystemError: error return without exception set Exception ignored in: . at 0x11489dc50> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Development &
>   Product/Project/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
>   line 1171, in 
>       if tokenName in fields), None) SystemError: error return without exception set Exception ignored in: . at 0x11489dc50> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Development &
>   Product/Project/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
>   line 1171, in 
>       if tokenName in fields), None) SystemError: error return without exception set Exception ignored in: . at 0x11489dc50> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Development &
>   Product/Project/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
>   line 1171, in 
>       if tokenName in fields), None) SystemError: error return without exception set Exception ignored in: . at 0x11489dc50> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Development &
>   Product/Project/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
>   line 1171, in 
>       if tokenName in fields), None) SystemError: error return without exception set Exception ignored in: .new_request.. at
>   0x11489dd00> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py",
>   line 169, in 
>       if all(getattr(body, stream_prop, None) for stream_prop in SystemError: error return without exception set

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
Flask>=0.12
httplib2>=0.10.3
google-api-python-client>=1.6.4
googleapis-common-protos>=1.3.5
uritemplate>=3.00
six>=1.6.1
oauth2client>=4.1.2
beautifulsoup4>=4.6.0
bson>=0.4.8
python-dateutil>=2.6.1
mysql-connector-python-rf>=2.1.3
nltk>=3.2.5
pandas>=0.20.3
matplotlib>=2.1.0
plotly>=2.0.0
cufflinks>=0.12.0
stripe>=1.66
loggly-python-handler
mailchimp3
gunicorn>=19.7.0
rollbar
python3-memcached
pympler
flask-talisman
flask_sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy
Flask-Testing
scikit-learn
scipy
tldextract
flask-static-compress
csscompressor
slimit
boto3
google-cloud-language
ujson
redis
sendgrid
```

Comment: I think that's not all of your error, it is between the error, please post all error because of some time first error causes a lot of errors.

Comment: You are right - I've edited my question with additional console content.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this - I went to double-check my exception settings to ensure Python exceptions were Enabled.

Instructions here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206601165-How-to-enable-stopping-on-unhandled-exceptions-